# На странице не показываются optgroup в select, добавленные скриптом

Tags: javascript, html

Довольно странная ситуация. Есть пользовательский [скрипт](https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Snowolf/GS_delete.js), который добавляет в `select` ещё одну группу и опции для выбора.

В код страницы они добавляются. Но [браузер их не отображает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msFSf.jpg). Классы и стили одинаковые со стандартной группой.

Что тут может быть в теории не так? Почему браузеры могут не отображать присутствующие в коде элементы? Дело тут явно не в скрипте. В какую сторону копать?

Если скопировать весь код страницы в файл и запустить локально, всё работает. Чертовщина.

Comment: А это точно настоящий селект, а не что-то на js? На скриншоте ничерта не видно

Comment: На скриншоте не видно, есть ли в `optgroup` вложенные `option`. Если нет, то возможно в стилях прописан `optgroup:empty {display: none}` и пустые группы отображаться не будут